# setPriority() deletes priority

Tags: firebase

I'm working with ordered data and ran into this problem:

I add items to a location with push() and set their priority to their creation date in milliseconds so they are ordered by date. When I try to change the order of the items I find the next, or previous (if there's no next) item and get it's priority, then I add or substract one and set the priority of the moved item to the result. I fetch the priority ok, but when I call setPriority() the item loses the priority. Exporting the item with the graphical debugger returns no priority for each item moved. Returns correct priority for unmoved items.

Some code:

```
/* id is the id of the div being moved
using jquery ui's sortable
div id's are formed like "item_" + firebaseref.name()
*/
name = id.substr(id.indexOf('_') + 1);
id2 = $('#' + id).next().attr('id');
if(id2){
    name2 = id2.substr(id2.indexOf('_') + 1);
    itemRef = rootRef.child('path/to/my/items/'+name2);
    itemRef.once('value', function (dataSnapshot){
        var pr = Number(dataSnapshot.getPriority()),
        myRef = rootRef.child('path/to/my/items/'+name);
        myRef.setPriority(pr - 1); // tried this or toString as below
    });
} else {
// try previous item
    id2 = $('#' + id).prev().attr('id');
    if(id2){
        name2 = id2.substr(id2.indexOf('_') + 1);
        itemRef = rootRef.child('path/to/my/items/'+name2);
        itemRef.once('value', function (dataSnapshot){
            var pr = Number(dataSnapshot.getPriority()) + 1,
            myRef = rootRef.child('path/to/my/items/'+name);
            myRef.setPriority(pr.toString());
        });
    }
}
```

I had a 'child_moved' listener but I'm not using it now. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the priority is a number when you get it? You might want to do a `parseInt` on it just to be certain.

Comment: Offhand I don't see anything wrong with your code.  Can you post a full sample (e.g. as a jsfiddle) so we can reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Definitely a number. I forced the priorities to be 10, 20, 30 and the code works as intended (p.e. the 30 ordered before the 20 becomes 19) Could it be an issue with my priorities being too long? When exported priorities are like: "1.355960702078E12", getPriority returns "1355962092412". It would be annoying, using a timestamp as priority sounded smart :)

Comment: Sorry, priority numbers are not from the same item in my comment. Hope you get the idea.

Comment: I second Michael's comment. Can you provide a link to a JSFiddle or another fully working (failing) example?

Comment: There you go:
http://jsfiddle.net/QKR2G/7/
I added 8 items for you to play with. Drag one to change it's order and rerun the fiddle. On redraw you will see it's priority changing to null (you can see the priority clicking the plus sign)

Merry Christmas! :)

Comment: Thanks for this. It's a bug. Answer is below...

Comment: We just deployed a fix for this. Thanks again for reporting the issue. Can you give it another try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Firebase. I'm not sure of the cause at this point but it appears that numbers larger than a certain size are not being properly saved. We'll investigate and update this answer when complete.

**Update**: This bug has been resolved. Give it another try!

Comment: Is this problem in again? Im running 2..5.2  and have the same issue, when i convert the priority to a string it woks fine...